# When you ask something with 'why', you can anwer with 'when'?

Tags: questions

> Child: Mister Jackie is a bad man.
>
> Detective: Why is he a bad man, sweetie?
>
> Child: He follows me into the bathroom.
>
> Detective: ***Why*** does he do that?
>
> Child: ***When*** I have to go.

It's a dialogue from a TV show.
I'm not sure it's ***'why'*** or ***'when'*** but the script says it's ***'why'***.

Detective asked '***Why*** does he do that', but why he anwered '***When*** I have to go'?
I can't understand what it means.
Please help me to understand it perfectly!

(My native language is not English. Please be kind to me. :-))

Comment: Firstly, you can't expect a dialogue with a young child to be an example of perfect grammar. Obviously this is a delicate subject and the child doesn't answer the detective's question directly. Instead of saying _why_ the man comes into the bathroom, he/she hints at the circumstances when this happens (when they are using the toilet).

Comment: So it's not perfect grammar. Thank you for telling me that!

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the grammar of the child's answer, it's just not a direct answer to the question. You can't assume from what a child says in an embarrassing conversation that it's 'correct' to answer a 'why' question with 'when'.

Comment: It is grammatical, but so is 'colourless green ideas sleep furiously'. It doesn't make perfect sense in the context, however, as as Kate has said, it's a child, and a delicate subject.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the child is just misinterpreting the question a bit. The detective asked "why", but the child interpreted this as meaning "under what circumstances".

Or he could just be phrasing the answer poorly, meaning "Because I have to go."

All these concepts are easily conflated, especially by a child in distress.

Comment: Thank you for detailed commenting!